# What is the best way to identify which syslog daemon is running on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, csh

I'm writing Linux shell script (sh, bash or csh) to identify which syslog daemon is running.
What is the best way to do it?
Since I only consider RHEL and rpm based destribution, Debian and its derivatives can be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, *syslog-ng* and *rsyslog* (the default) are the only ones available on RHEL. You could either probe the process space, see which process currently holds `/var/log/syslog` open or simply check which syslog daemon is installed (though, it's possible to have them both installed at the same time).

```bsh
$ lsof /var/log/messages /var/log/syslog 2>&1 | grep syslog
$ rpm -q rsyslog syslog-ng
$ pgrep -u root syslog | xargs ps -p
```

Answer (score 1):

One could parse the output of lsof to see which processes have the file /var/log/syslog open, a very crude example would be:

```
sudo lsof | grep /var/log/syslog | cut -f1 -d' '
```

If you are using a single distribution there may be more elegant ways of checking.

Answer (score 0):

On a debian-based system, run the following script to see what's installed:

```
dpkg-query -l '*syslog*' | grep ii
```

This will give you output similar to the following

```
ii  rsyslog  7.4.4-1ubuntu2.3  i386  reliable system and kernel logging daemon
```

That way you don't have to grep files etc. Hope it helps you out.